# Android: Gradient border with translucent background

Tags: android, xml

I'm trying to achieve this effect where the rounded rectangle background has a gradient border and a translucent background (designed in Figma).

[image]

The closest I've come to achieving this is doing a layer list where the first layer is a gradient and the second layer is a translucent solid color stacked on top. However, this doesn't work since I can still see the first gradient layer. This is what it looks like.

[image]

Here is the code for it too:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <gradient
                android:angle="45"
                android:endColor="#EB00FF"
                android:startColor="#0085FF"
                android:type="linear" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item
        android:bottom="4dp"
        android:left="4dp"
        android:right="4dp"
        android:top="4dp">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="30dp"/>
            <solid android:color="@color/transparent_white" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

How can I achieve the desired effect of a translucent background with a gradient border?

Comment: increase the transparency of the colors used in gradient drawable. https://i.stack.imgur.com/mo5Pt.png just adjust the alpha according to your needs.